# Puppeteer page.on(console... not working as expected

Tags: node.js, automation, puppeteer

I am attempting to use `console.log` inside of `page.evaluate` such that the information will log to Node's console. The guide on [pptr.dev](https://pptr.dev/guides/debugging) provides the following code snippet

```
page.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text()));
await page.evaluate(() => console.log(`url is ${location.href}`));
```

This code generally works, but I have run into a problem while testing on my local machine where `console.log` appears to stop working. Here is the code that I am running:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

async function run() {

    const puppeterOptions = {
        headless: false,
        executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe'
    };


    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(puppeterOptions);
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    page.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text()));
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        console.log("just some text");
    });

    await page.goto('https://localhost');

    await page.evaluate(() => {
        console.log("just some text 2");
    });

    await browser.close();    
}

run();
```

In this example, `just some text` will be output to the Node console as I would expect, but `just some text 2` will not. What makes this a little more frustrating is that if I change `https://localhost` to something like `https://www.google.com` the code works as expected and I see both `just some text` and `just some text 2` in my Node console.  Further, if I open Developer Tools I see `just some text 2` in the console when navigating to Google but that text does not show up in my console when looking at my local.

When running against my local I get 2 outputs in the node console after `page.goto`: a 404 issue for a missing favicon and a DOM error (password field exists outside of a FORM tag) but any other calls to `console.log` do not show up in the Node console and they also don't show up in the Developer Tools console, either (this is not the case if I got to Google, my logs appear in both Node and the Developer Tools console).

AFAIK there is nothing special about the code I am running Puppeteer against, it is just a basic internal tool.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't actually a problem with Puppeteer.  A previous developer wrote a script that overrides the functionality of `console.log` and instead of sending the content to the console it sends the content to a hidden DIV (in addition to some other things).  This script causes no content to show up in the browsers console and thus it doesn't show up when Puppeteer is being run.

For a variety of reasons I can't change the script that is causing the issue in Puppeteer.  To overcome this problem I wrote a function that would log to Node's console and then made it available inside Puppeteer via `exposeFunction`.  Implementation follows.

```
let nodeLogger = (msg: string) => {
    console.log(msg);
}

await page.exposeFunction("nodeLogger", nodeLogger);

await page.evaluate(async () => {
    await nodeLogger("Node test in eval");
    ...
});
```